# npm azure-storage download file as base64

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-storage) to download the file from azure to local node server. But I do not want to save the file in local server and then read it to convert to base64, I want to directly convert it to base64. How can I achieve this?

```
 this.blobService.getBlobToStream('pictures', path, fs.createWriteStream(`./src/temp/${filename}.jpeg`), function(error, result, response) {
                if (!error) {
                    resolve({ message: `Items in container pictures:`, data: result});
                } else {
                    reject(error);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Built-in Node only supports ecnode `Buffer` type to `base64`, since you don't want to download blob to local server, you have to use external module to encode `stream`.

`npm install base64-stream` then use code below.

```
var base64 = require('base64-stream');
...
this.blobService.createReadStream(container, path).pipe(base64.encode()).pipe(res);
```

Notice that in your [later question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50796593/how-do-i-convert-readable-image-stream-into-base64-without-saving-locally), you specify `Content-Type` using

```
res.header('Content-Type', properties['contentType']);
```

`Content-Type` setting should be omitted. In my test, if set `Content-Type` successfully, the image will be downloaded as attachment instead of being displayed as inline content. Your code succeeds because it actually sets `Content-Type` to `undefined`.

Properties you use is a BlobResult(Json format)with blob info

```
BlobResult {
  container: xxx,
  ...
  contentSettings:
   { contentType: 'image/jpg',
     contentMD5: 'uNkt2WJ75X13TjQbfY7qkA==' },
  ... 
}
```

So `contentType` should be used in this format `properties.contentSettings.contentType`