# How do I convert readable image stream into base64 without saving locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-storage

I want to convert an image in azure to base64. How can I achieve this using azure-storage package?

```
this.blobService.getBlobProperties(
                'container',
                path,
                (err, properties, status)=> {
                    if (err) {
                         res.send(502, "Error fetching file: %s", err.message);
                    } else if (!status.isSuccessful) {
                        res.send(502, "The file %s does not exist", fileName)
                    } else {
                         res.header('Content-Type', properties['contentType']);
                         this.blobService.createReadStream('container', path,(error,response)=>{
                         }).pipe(res);
                    }
                });
```

The response I get is like this, I want to convert this(octet/stream) to base64.

[image]

Comment: buff.toString('base64');

Comment: where should I give this?

Comment: your file buffer - res.body.toString('base64')

Comment: http://stackabuse.com/encoding-and-decoding-base64-strings-in-node-js/

Answer (score 0):

Try

`var dataUrl="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAA..";
 var buffer = new Buffer(dataUrl.split(",")[1], 'base64');`

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in Node.js method to do that. Some 3rd npm packages you can use, for example, https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-stream